# jQuery XmlHttpRequest Cache-Control being ignored

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery

I'm using google chrome and I noticed that every time I do an XHR request I get the following headers put on the request:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

If you read the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/ it says the following

> If the user agent implements a HTTP cache it should respect
>   Cache-Control headers in author request headers (e.g. Cache-Control:
>   no-cache bypasses the cache). It must not send Cache-Control or Pragma
>   request headers automatically unless the end user explicitly requests
>   such behavior (e.g. by reloading the page).

Well I'm trying the following:

```
$.ajax(myUrl, {
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json'
    cache: true,
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=200' 
    }
  })
```

As you can see I'm explicitly setting the Cache-Control header in hopes of getting a cached copy of my resource. Well Chrome seems to ignore the Cache-Control header.

Is it possible to not send the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header when making an XHR request?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This was a dumb mistake. I had the Developer Tools set to "Disable Cache". That's why it was always adding the cache-control header. If this ever happens to you make sure you make sure that box is not checked.

Raul

Comment: Yes, note that Firebug also has "Disable Browser Cache" in the "Net" menu.  I've been bitten by this one, too.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why native fetch() wasn't returning data from the cache, even when Cache-Control headers were being set correctly by the server. Thank you for helping correct this oversight, it was driving me mad.

Comment: I spent so long trying to track this down.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I just tested it and your code works fine, except for a missing comma.

Open the network tab, then try this in the console on this page:

```
$.ajax('http://stackoverflow.com/', {
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: true,
    headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=123' 
    }
})
```

Check the network tab again, click the request you just made, and click the "headers" tab. You will see that the request was sent with the `Cache-Control` header you provided.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It was my own fault. I should have checked the developer tools to make sure that I didn't have caching disabled.